# Is there a way to enable macros once in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I have a excel 2007 macro-enabled file (xlsm) that I want to share with a lot of users, but it requires enabling macros each time the spreadsheet is opened.

I know that you can change the macro settings to "enable all macros" and put the spreadsheet in a trusted location. I'm looking for a more user-friendly to do this.

I'm trying to to see if there is another option before having to digitally sign the code.

Office 2010 looks like it will remember that you enable macros. Most of our users have 2007 though.

Comment: What you want to do is considered to be hacking and outside of Microsoft best practises.

Trusted locations were designed for what you want to do.   Its a much easier option than digitally signing.

Comment: Trusted locations was one of my top picks, but this is for a big organization where the spreadsheet will be passed around and maybe even stored on some network shares. We didn't want to limit how users save their files. Do you know a good tool generate a csr for a code signing certificate. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just do what you said, digitally sign, or put in trusted location. You could also create a executable program that opens the workbook that suppresses the macro warning when opening the workbook. Really, there aren't any "friendly" ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a patch or trick I missed. It's weird how you only have to enable the macros once in Office 2010 and not 2007. I'm veering towards the digital signature.

Comment: If you feel like my answer is correct feel free to mark it as such.